# Skip Counting a page

Tags: page-numbering

Initially I wanted to skip counting my first page so I used `\pagenumbering{gobble}` under `\maketitle` and on the page where I wanted to start, I used `\pagenumbering{arabic}`

But now I want to skip numbering a page in the middle of the document and when I use the method above to 'gobble' the page numbering and use arabic for the next, it resets the counter...

So I thought of using `\setcounter{page}{20}` because I'm skipping the 20th page and applying that to the next, but even this didn't fix the problem, the counter still starts from 1...

Here is the fragment:

```
\pagenumbering{gobble}
This is a normal text paragraph, on one page without numbering
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{20}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
This page's numbering starts at 1
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Normally, I would put `\stepcounter{page}` on the page before the page of which the numbering should be skipped. But without any code provided it is hard to tell where the problem could be ...

Comment: So, wouldn't `\addtocounter{page}{1}` work?

Comment: As you've (re)discovered, `\pagenumbering` resets the `page` counter to `1`.

Comment: Never use `\pagenumbering{gobble}`.

Comment: The titlepage environment does all that for you..

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you insert the instruction `\thispagestyle{empty}` on the page that's not supposed to show a page number and the instruction `\addtocounter{page}{-1}` on the following page.

A full MWE (minimum working example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]  % 2 pages of filler text
\clearpage     % jump to next page
\lipsum[11-12] % 2 more paragraphs of filler text, on 1 page
\thispagestyle{empty}   % don't show page number, on this page only
\clearpage     % jump to next page
\addtocounter{page}{-1} % decrement the page counter
\lipsum[13-22] % 2 more pages of filler text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this also mean I can use something like:
\addtocounter{page}{+1}

Comment: Try `\addtocounter{page}{1}`.

Comment: @AbhimanyuSareen - Instead of `\addtocounter{page}{1}`, which is unsemantic, I'd write `\stepcounter{page}`.